# Operator overload of typedef type

Tags: c++, boost, typedef, odeint

I'm trying to use the QVM and ODEINT library. I'm using the `qvm::vec<double,n>` through a typedef as my *state_type*.  I would like to use the subscript operator for ´state_type´. (To my knowledge ODEINT requires the subscript operator.) My problem is that QVM access operator is ´A(v)´ and doesn't implement the subscript operator. How would you overload the operator or solve this problem?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/qvm.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 value_type;

typedef boost::qvm::vec<value_type,3> triple;

int main()
{
 \\some code
}
```

Comment: Typedefs are *aliases*, they don’t declare new types. Consequently you cannot create overloaded operators for them. You need to generate a façade instead — that is, wrap it inside your own type, which you need to explicitly implement.

Comment: Unrelated: [Why should I **not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: Would do you mean with facade and how do I create it?

Comment: Where did you learn that odeint requires the subscript operator? They have an example of using `std::list`, which doesn't have one...

Comment: Please provide some more code, even if it won't work, to help us understand what your problem is.